Why do precalculated circuits from the internet not work in simulation software?
I was studying a common collector amplifier (CCA) for one of my projects. I was interested to see if a precalculated circuit from the internet would work for me in LTspice.
I got one website and tested this circuit in simulation software. It did not work for the output values which the website promised. I was getting curious if the calculations could be wrong, but I have seen they are correct so far.
Below is the circuit I tested. The circuit has pure resistors and does not have any capacitors. I was guessing it should amplify DC and not AC as input, but I also tested them and no, it does not work for both. Here is the circuit and the .asc file for LTspice. I also attached the website from which I obtained the circuit:
https://www.electronics-lab.com/article/common-collector-amplifier/

Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 256 32 64 32
WIRE 320 32 256 32
WIRE 256 128 256 32
WIRE 320 144 320 112
WIRE 64 176 64 112
WIRE 64 176 -16 176
WIRE 192 176 64 176
WIRE 64 240 64 176
WIRE 256 240 256 224
WIRE 352 240 256 240
WIRE 416 240 352 240
WIRE -16 288 -16 256
WIRE 176 320 64 320
WIRE 256 320 176 320
WIRE 352 320 256 320
WIRE 176 352 176 320
FLAG 416 240 out
FLAG 320 144 0
FLAG -16 288 0
FLAG 176 352 0
SYMBOL res 48 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 20k
SYMBOL res 48 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 20k
SYMBOL res 240 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res 336 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL npn 192 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N2222
SYMBOL voltage -16 160 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 320 16 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 10
TEXT -50 376 Left 2 !.tran 1m



Edit: The output voltage is much less than is given.  It should be nearly the same as input and output current is poor.
Edit2:
I have seen that the previous tutorial of author on the following website is being described the issue about AC coupling capacitors:
Full CEA configuration
https://www.electronics-lab.com/article/common-emitter-amplifier/


This is an AC amplifier.  You need to AC couple your input (add a series capacitor) so you can inject your AC signal without disturbing the DC operating point.  How the 1V voltage source is connected right now is ruining that operating point.

Yeah, I guessed so. But did you check the calculations on the website? Why are not there any capacitors?

You need to add two capacitors, one between the Vin and the base terminal and the second one between the emitter and the load resistance. Why did the author of the page forget about those two capacitors? We do not know, ask the author.

@Acknowledge I did.  You're missing context by skipping to that specific tutorial.  In the previous Common Emitter tutorial, it covers the difference between the DC biasing equivalent circuit and the full circuit.  I still think it's presented poorly, but regardless you need some basics in transistor-based amplifiers before you can copy a diagram into LTspice and expect it to work.

Thanks, a lot. I got it. It was really a mystery how to make this circuit working with those values.

The circuit operates correctly. What are your expectations for its performance? As demonstrated, 1 volt is applied to the base of Q1, turning the transistor on and developing 0.36 volts on the emitter. It functions perfectly doing nothing.
If you remove the 1-volt drive, the base voltage rises to 4.62 volts while the emitter goes to 3.9 volts, precisely as it should. It does nothing except turn on harder.
Your circuit was made to do nothing. Test the second circuit by applying an AC signal to the input and observe the results.



The circuit which has been demonstrated by the author on the website has noticed the readers about the capacitors which are not present. It is way to have an idea about the working principle of amps. Of course, the calculations are okay. You are right. TY.

The calculation you did is correct. But the author said that the voltage gain is nearly 1 and current gain is a lot higher. This issue made me curious while simulating in LTSpice. Correct me if I am wrong. The calculations are on the website which I attached at the beginning of my post.

The second circuit, you have presented is working as being expected. As a matter of fact, the issue was about the first circuit. What you have demonstrated lastly has nothing with the first one. So I agree with you.

@Acknowledge But the second circuit shows what the common collector amplifier should look like.
